# MongoDB CPU usage gets 100%

Tags: mongodb, scala, morphia

We have around 100 IoT devices which get connected to the cloud and sends data to cloud every 10 seconds.

We tested on 2vcore/4G RAM and 8 vcore/16G RAM. The CPU usage increases to 200% and 800% respectively in a short time. The established TCP connections are around 106.

Is it because we created too many mongoldb connections or the frequency of writing to mongoDB is too fast?

I think Object in Scala is like singleton so it should only create one DBHelper object? But does the code in DBHelper create each datastore for each TCP connection?

1.DBHelper.scala:

```
  Object DBHelper{
      var datastore= morphia.createDataStore(…………….);
  }
```

2.MqttClient.java

```
  mqttPushClient.setCallback(pushCallBack);
```

3.

```
 public class PushCallback implements MqttCallback {
      public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
       //calls DBHelper and save message to mongoDB
   }
 }
```

Comment: Scala objects are singleton, unless you are not using a method to recreate DB connections.

Comment: If possible share github link, I can take a look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should only create one `MongoClient` and reuse that as much as you can.  `MongoClient` has its own internal connection pool and so can manage all that for you.  Each time you create a new client, it has to reestablish a connection and load up certain bits of metadata.  So, as much as you can, create the one client and the one `Datastore` for that connection and just reuse it us much as you can.